# What to do if your question becomes inactive too quickly?

Tags: discussion, questions

Many times, I have asked a question that one or two people replied to in a comment asking a question. After I reply to them sometimes nobody replies to my comment, nobody answers the question, and it becomes inactive. I understand that this is a site with many users and my question will quickly get buried under hundreds of new ones, but what should I do if this happens? One example of such a question is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47276244/mysqli-procedural-get-single-value-from-table).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are asked for more information in a comment, don't provide the information in another comment, edit your question to include the requested information, then reply to the comment to say you have updated the question.

The reason for doing it that way is that all the information needed to answer should be in your question. Not everyone is going to read through the comments and and if they don't see an answerable question, they won't be able to answer (and may down-vote or even vote to close the question).

Also, editing your question will bump it up in the list of all questions, which may get some people to give it a second look (don't abuse this by making trivial edits just to get attention).

Answer (score 3):

To add to Blackwood's answer, you can also provide a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) to your question once you have enough reputation on the site. This will 'pin' your question to the question list when filtered for bounties. It also incentivizes people to read and answer your question, because doing so puts them in the running for a big reputation gain.